# Added the cipher SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 in Websphere app server but it is not visible in the logs and handshake exception is happening

Tags: encryption, websphere, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception

We are doing an integration between websphere and a TLSv1.2 system and it is throwing handshake exception because of the cipher mismatch [certificate and client side tls versions matching]. We have added the required cipher to the server [SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256] but it is not showing in the logs. so the handshake is failed. [as per the destination system network team, all the below listed ciphers are of tlsv1 so it cannot be added to their server]

**From SSL logs:**
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RENEGO_PROTECTION_REQUEST]

What could be the reason for this ?

is there any way we can add this required cipher from java code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Where did you add the cipher? Inside QoP? The cipher SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 is disabled by default - I think by adding this to the server may not work. Try adding the custom property com.ibm.websphere.tls.disabledAlgorithms=none.

Comment: Yes I have added that to QoP. I assume your suggesion is to keep the cipher in QoP and add this additional custom propery. I will try that. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: I have added this and that dint resolve the issue. And i searched for this cipher[SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ] in full logs for the last few days and I can see that in the cipher list for some other service connections. So now I am totally confused why it is not coming for this specific service. I made the REST client call similar to all the other services also..

Comment: I want to ask where did you add the custom property? under JVM or Global Security?